# co-integration - which regression

Tags: cointegration

I have a very basic, perhaps silly question regarding finding the coefficient of Co-integration. Suppose some tests (say ADF) tells me that $X$ and $Y$ are co-integrated.

Then how do I get the relationship?

For example, if I regress $Y = a_1 + b_1 X + e$, I would get estimated value of $b_1^{'} = \rho_{Y, X} \sigma_Y / \sigma_X$, and if I regress $X = a_2 + b_2 Y + e$, I would get estimated value of $b_2^{'} = \rho_{Y, X} \sigma_X / \sigma_Y$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are co-integrated as per definition, then one should expect $b_1 * b_2 = 1$ etc. But, by the very process of the two regressions, the estimated values of $b_1^{'} * b_2^{'} = \rho_{Y, X}^2$.

Can regression be used to solve for the coefficient used to define the Co-integration?

Comment: because $Y = a_1 + b_1 X$ can be written as $X = -(a_1/b_1) + (1/b_1) Y$, and where $X$ and $Y$ are co-integrated, by definition, $(1/b_1) = b_2$.

Comment: You'll notice that you don't actually use the fact that the series are cointegrated anywhere in your argument; the fact that the two least squares slope estimates aren't necessarily inverses is general and well-known. Intuitively, the "squares" you're minimizing aren't the same (vertical vs horizontal distance from the line of best fit).